# Create array of literals and columns from List of Strings in Spark

Tags: arrays, list, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to define functions in Scala that take a list of strings as input, and converts them into the columns passed to the dataframe array arguments used in the code below.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))).toDF("foo","bar")
val df2 = df
        .withColumn("columnArray",array(df("foo").cast("String"),df("bar").cast("String")))
        .withColumn("litArray",array(lit("foo"),lit("bar")))
```

More specifically, I would like to create functions `colFunction` and `litFunction` (or just one function if possible) that takes a list of strings as an input parameter and can be used as follows:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))).toDF("foo","bar")
val colString = List("foo","bar")
val df2 = df
         .withColumn("columnArray",array(colFunction(colString))
         .withColumn("litArray",array(litFunction(colString)))
```

I have tried mapping the `colString` to an Array of columns with all the transformations but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Spark 2.2+**:

Support for `Seq`, `Map` and `Tuple` (`struct`) literals has been added in [SPARK-19254](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19254). According [to tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/14bb398fae974137c3e38162cefc088e12838258/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/ColumnExpressionSuite.scala#L720):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

typedLit(Seq("foo", "bar"))
```

**Spark < 2.2**

Just `map` with `lit` and wrap with `array`:

```
def asLitArray[T](xs: Seq[T]) = array(xs map lit: _*)

df.withColumn("an_array", asLitArray(colString)).show
// +---+---+----------+
// |foo|bar|  an_array|
// +---+---+----------+
// |  1|  1|[foo, bar]|
// |  2|  2|[foo, bar]|
// |  3|  3|[foo, bar]|
// +---+---+----------+
```

Regarding transformation from `Seq[String]` to `Column` of type `Array` this functionality is already provided by:

```
def array(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column
```

or

```
def array(cols: Column*): Column
```

Example:

```
val cols = Seq("bar", "foo")

cols match { case x::xs => df.select(array(x, xs:_*)) 
// or 
df.select(array(cols map col: _*))
```

Of course all columns have to be of the same type.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's that thing called? `array(xs map lit: _*)`, seems confusing to me.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto You're excused ;) Seriously though it is Scala way to unpack arguments. `array` implementation which we use here has a following signature: `array(cols: Column*)` where `*` marks varargs. It means it can be called like `array(x, y, z)`. Since we pass a sequence it has to be unpacked which is marked by `: _*`. It is equivalent to Python `def foo(*args): ...; foo(*[x, y, z])`.

Comment: much appreciated @zero323! I still can't figure out how I would define what I called a colFunction(colString) in my question, where I would need an array of the column values (and not literals) returned. Is this also possible using a similar function to the one you supplied?

Comment: You don't need custom function. Just use `array` directly like `df.select(array($"foo", $"bar"))`.

Comment: @zero323 this will be part of a bigger process where a List[List[String]] is processed, so I am looking for a function that converts a List[String] to an array of literals (which you have already kindly supplied), but also as an array of the actual column values. Is this possible at all?

Comment: df.withColumn("degree_levels", typedLit(Seq("masters", "doctorates", "magisters", "bachelors", "associates")))

Answer (score 1):

*To **create** df containing array type column* (3 alternatives):

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (Seq("foo", "bar")),
    (Seq("baz", "qux")),
).toDF("col_name")
```

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (Array("foo", "bar")),
    (Array("baz", "qux")),
).toDF("col_name")
```

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (List("foo", "bar")),
    (List("baz", "qux")),
).toDF("col_name")
```

*To **add** col of array type*:

- providing existent col names

  ```
  df.withColumn("new_col", array("col1", "col2"))
  ```
- providing a *list* of existent col names

  ```
  df.withColumn("new_col", array(list_of_str map col: _*))
  ```
- providing literal values (2 alternatives)

  ```
  df.withColumn("new_col", typedLit(Seq("foo", "bar")))
  df.withColumn("new_col", array(lit("foo"), lit("bar")))
  ```
- providing a *list* of literal values (2 alternatives)

  ```
  df.withColumn("new_col", typedLit(list_of_str))
  df.withColumn("new_col", array(list_of_str map lit: _*))
  ```