# Spark, DataFrame: Get all distinct strings from many columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Data**: `DataFrame` that has 15 string columns.

**Goal**: To create a list that contains the distinct strings in all the 15 columns.

**Example**: if the word "guitar" appears once or more times in the first column, as well as in the forth column, it has to appear once in the final list.

**Suggested solution but not ideal**: A UDF is an option to concat all the columns in one new columns, then I can process that column with a `CountVectorizer` that will extract the vocabulary. But the UDFs are limited as they accept a maximum 10 input parameters (i.e. I can't pass more than 10 columns to a UDF), so this solution has to implement two UDFs, the first to concatenate 10 columns, the second to concatenate the output of the first UDF with the next 5 columns.

I am looking for a more efficient compact solution for this issue, and more generally, a work around solution to the problem of limited number of input parameters for UDFs.

Comment: A few precisions, if I may ask : do you want to collect to a list (e.g. driver-side), or to a dataframe ? Is switching to RDD an option for your case ? (Side note : array_concat + count vectorizer offer a good solution for your question I guess, but that is because your use case is of strings, not arbitrary types)

Comment: No problem in working with DataFrames and RDDs, does array_concat accept more that number of columns?

Comment: Appart that it is not `array_concat`, just `array`, sorry for that, yes, it can. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419307/create-array-of-literals-and-columns-from-list-of-strings-in-spark-sql for something kind of related. I'm looking for something better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spark-sql function `array` can map any number of colons (of the same type) to an array-column of that type.

From there on, you can create a UDF on the array type, or for your case, use the CountVectorizer as suggested.

```
scala> val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("a1", "b1", "c1"), ("a2", "b2", "c2"))).toDF("a", "b", "c")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> data.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a2| b2| c2|
+---+---+---+

scala> data.select(array("a", "b", "c")).show
+--------------+
|array(a, b, c)|
+--------------+
|  [a1, b1, c1]|
|  [a2, b2, c2]|
+--------------+
```

There is simpler, though, than a CountVectorizer :

```
scala> data.select(explode(array("a", "b", "c"))).distinct.show
+---+
|col|
+---+
| b2|
| c1|
| a2|
| b1|
| a1|
| c2|
+---+
```

If going RDD directly is fine with you, there is still simpler (and probably faster) :

```
scala> data.rdd.flatMap(r=>r.toSeq).distinct.collect
res4: Array[Any] = Array(b2, a1, a2, c1, c2, b1)
```