# Spark: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I have searched through other answers related to this question and they have not helped.

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe. This column will have a datatype of `Seq[CaseClass]`. At first I thought it might be that spark doesn't support collection type columns but this isn't the case.

Here is an example of the code I am trying to run. I just want to add an empty Seq[CaseClass] to each row that I can append to later on.

```
case class Employee(name: String)
val emptyEmployees: Seq[Employee] = Seq()
df.withColumn("Employees", lit(emptyEmployees))
```

But then I get this error being thrown at the line with the `withColumn`

```
Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type classscala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using spark 2.2+, then just change `lit()` to `typedLit()`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35420501/2639647) answer.

```
case class Employee(name: String)
val emptyEmployees: Seq[Employee] = Seq()
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("foo")).toDF("foo")
df.withColumn("Employees", typedLit(emptyEmployees)).show()
```

shows us:

```
+---+---------+
|foo|Employees|
+---+---------+
|foo|       []|
+---+---------+
```

**Update**

For 2.1, the linked answer above for that version works by converting your `lit(Array)` into an `array()` of `lit()`s (with some magic scala syntax). In your case, this will work because the array is empty.

```
def asLitArray[T](xs: Seq[T]) = array(xs map lit: _*)

case class Employee(name: String)

val emptyEmployees: Seq[Employee] = Seq()
val df = spark.createDataset(Seq("foo")).toDF("foo")

df.withColumn("Employees", asLitArray(emptyEmployees)).show()
```

Which has the same result:

```
+---+---------+
|foo|Employees|
+---+---------+
|foo|       []|
+---+---------+
```

To actually have something in your `Seq` would require a slightly different function.

Comment: I am using spark 2.1.0 unfortunately and the other solution for <2.2 doesn't make sense because I don't know what `map()` is for. I don't have enough reputation points to ask what it is as a comment