# Getting data type mismatch: differing types in column filter((array<string> and string))

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

While trying to filter a column for checking empty dataset, I am getting below error of type mismatch.

```
cannot resolve '(`sellers` = '[]')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`sellers` = '[]')' (array<string> and string).;;
```

I have tried below code but its not working and throwing above error:

```
var sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDF.select("sellers")
sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDFSelectSellers.filter(col("sellers") === "[]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sellersDFSelectSellers.filter(col("sellers") === typedLit(Seq()))
```

I managed to reproduce

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, typedLit}

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Spark app")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

case class MyClass(sellers: Seq[String])
val sellersDF = Seq(MyClass(Seq("a", "b")), MyClass(Seq("c", "d", "e")), MyClass(Seq())).toDS()
sellersDF.show()
//+---------+
//|  sellers|
//+---------+
//|   [a, b]|
//|[c, d, e]|
//|       []|
//+---------+
var sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDF.select("sellers")
  //org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(sellers = '[]')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(sellers = '[]')' (array<string> and string)
//sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDFSelectSellers.filter(col("sellers") === "[]") 
sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDFSelectSellers.filter(col("sellers") === typedLit(Seq()))
sellersDFSelectSellers.show()
//+-------+
//|sellers|
//+-------+
//|     []|
//+-------+
```

[Spark: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$ List()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107070/spark-unsupported-literal-type-class-scala-collection-immutable-nil-list)

Answer (score 0):

This code solved the problem.

```
val sellersDFSelectSellers = sellersDF.select("sellers")
val emptySellers = sellersDFSelectSellers.filter(size(col("sellers")) === 0)
```